# Foreign Key Null Issue in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am coding an application by using Spring Boot and etc. I have 2 tables called Book and User. There is a relationship between them called One-To-Many(User-Book). Book entity has a foreign key in its table. I want to do to that sometimes I want to fill the foreign data sometimes I do not want. How can I do that? In addition, When I enter a json object to postman, it gives an error. I want to write like an object and I want that the code can be work with any issue.

The json is that:

`{`

`"name":"Bomb",`

`"date":"March 1913",`

`"categoryId":2,`

`"authorId":2`

`}`

Book Entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
@Data
public class Book {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String date;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id",nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id",nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Author author;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",nullable = true)
    private User user;
}
```

BookCreateRequest

```
@Data
public class BookCreateRequest {
    private String name;
    private String date;
    private Long categoryId;
    private Long authorId;
    @Nullable
    private Long userId;
}
```

BookService's createOneBook method

```
public Book createOneBook(BookCreateRequest bookCreateRequest){
    Book book = new Book();

    Author author = authorRepository.findById(bookCreateRequest.getAuthorId()).orElse(null);
    User user = userRepository.findById(bookCreateRequest.getUserId()).orElse(null);
    Category category = categoryRepository.findById(bookCreateRequest.getCategoryId()).orElse(null);

    book.setAuthor(author);
    book.setUser(user);
    book.setCategory(category);
    book.setName(bookCreateRequest.getName());
    book.setDate(bookCreateRequest.getDate());

    bookRepository.save(book);
    return book;
}
```

I am coding an application by using Spring Boot and etc. I have 2 tables called Book and User. There is a relationship between them called One-To-Many(User-Book). Book entity has a foreign key in its table. I want to do to that sometimes I want to fill the foreign data sometimes I do not want. How can I do that? In addition, When I enter a json object to postman, it gives an error. I want to write like an object and I want that the code can be work with any issue.